# Work done in moving two superconductor rings infinite distance apart

Tags: homework-and-exercises, work, electromagnetic-induction

Superconductors have a property that magnetic flux linked with them will always remain
constant. Two identical superconducting rings each having self inductance $'L'$ carrying
current $'I'$ in same direction are placed together. Find work done against magnetic interaction in separating the rings to far away [infinite distance].
(Assuming that the mutual inductance of the two rings is $M = L$ in the initial position).

The answer is given as $2LI^2$.
The working is shown as $$U_{initial}= LI^2 + LI^2$$
$$U_{final} = 4LI^2$$
$$\therefore W = 2LI^2$$
No reason as to how the initial or final potential energy is obtained is given. I know that the formula for energy stored in an inductor is $\frac{1}{2}LI^2$ and mutual inductance is $\frac{1}{2}MI^2$($\frac{1}{2}LI^2$ in this case as well according to the problem). I know that at infinite seperation the mutual inductance becomes zero, yet I do not understand how the energy of the system has increased. It would be really helpful if I got a little explanation as to why or how this is correct.I know this is a homework problem, but if anyone were to consider clarifying my doubt as to how the values for $U_{initial}$ or $U_{final}$ is obtained, would be really helpful. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for the energy in a pair of mutual inductors is $$U=\frac{1}{2} L_1 I_1{}^2 + \frac{1}{2} L_2 I_2{}^2 + M I_1 I_2$$ so for $I_1=I_2=I$ and $L_1=L_2=L$ then $$U=LI^2+MI^2$$

So initially we have $M=L$ which gives us $$U_{initial}=2LI^2$$ The important thing to realize is that when we go to the final configuration we have $M\to 0$ because the fields do not overlap and $I \to 2I$ in order to keep the flux constant in each loop. This gives us $$U_{final}=4LI^2$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. If you could clarify how $I \to 2I$ when $M \to 0$, it would be really helpful for me.

Comment: That is required to keep the flux constant